# App Script trigger stops executing after closing sheet it is bound to

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script bound to a google sheet (linked to a form) which updates some values in it, makes an API call, fetches an image to embed in a mail and sends the mail to the sender using on form submit trigger. Everything works perfectly fine as long as the sheet is open in my browser. If any responses are received after closing the sheet in the browser, its almost as if the trigger isn't existent. Nothing shows up in executions as well. No failed executions or anything of that sort.

**Objective:**
When a user fills the form, a UID is generated & added to the sheet which is then embed in a QR code by making an API call. This QR code is also uploaded to google drive by that API call. The script then fetches this QR (png image) from drive, embeds it in a mail and sends it to the user.

Here is my code:

```
var ID_LENGTH = 20;

// Generates a random UID
function generateUID () {
  var ALPHABET = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  var rtn = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < ID_LENGTH; i++) {
    rtn += ALPHABET.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ALPHABET.length));
  }
  return rtn;
}

function autoResponder(e) {
  console.log("Trigger begin");

  // Get Active Sheet
  const sheetID = 'spreadsheetID';
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName('sheetName');

  var sheetname = ss.getName();
  
  // A function which returns a randomnly generated UID
  var responseId = generateUID() 

  // Append response ID and Present status to row
  var formrow = e.range.rowStart
  ss.getRange(formrow, 25).setValue(responseId);
  ss.getRange(formrow, 26).setValue("FALSE");

  // Make API call
  const api_url = `https://myapi.com/test`  
  var api_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api_url);
  console.log(api_response.getContentText());

  // Fetch Png from drive
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById('folder-id').getFilesByName(`${responseId}.png`).next().getBlob()

  var name = e.namedValues.Name
  var email = e.namedValues['Email address'][0]
  console.log(e.namedValues['Email address'][0])
  var adminEmail = "abc@xyz.com"

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "email subject",
    htmlBody: '<html>Some html code</html>',
    inlineImages:
      {
        image: file
      }
  });
  
}
```

After going through some other threads, I've tried the following:

1. The script was making use of e.source.getActiveSheet(). Tried replacing those usages with hard coded values.
2. Deleting and re creating the trigger.
3. Creating the trigger programmatically.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a google form and link it to a sheet.
2. Create a function in the app script bound to the sheet which sends an email to the user who filled the form.
3. In project triggers, add a onFormSubmit trigger for the sheet to execute that function.
4. Close any instances of the sheet that are open and submit the form.
   It is observed that the trigger won't be executed at all.

I can't figure where the issue is but it seems like my code is fine.
How can I make it such that the trigger activates even if the sheet is not open anywhere?
It's my first time posting here, apologies if I've missed anything or am not clear.

**UPDATE**: I played around more and can confirm its not the code. I created a simple function with just a console.log() statement and the trigger for that would also not execute on submitting the form. Tried from different google accounts as well. I came across this [bug thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762327). This issue of trigger not executing once sheet is closed has occurred before. It's possible that something is causing it to occur again.

**UPDATE 2**: Everything seems to be working fine all of a sudden. Maybe google fixed the issue on their end. I had created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/286297977) for the same and a few others also had the same problem. Fingers crossed it stays like this ! If it stops firing again, I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question to make it reproducible. Explain how your process  works and what triggers you are using. Also please share the code for the `generateUID()`

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly. Let me know if you need anything else @Twilight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been quite a while now and everything is working fine. After reading a lot of threads, it seems that the form submit trigger always has issues. The workaround suggested by other users is to use time driven triggers as a fallback.